# Where is the Front Controller using server:run in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony

Using plain old apache server, you make your request to Symfony using `localhost:80/acme/app.php/routes`

So `app.php` or `app_dev.php` **is** you Front Controller. Knowing this, you can forget almost it. But when you use the PHP built in server, you can access directly to `localhost:8000/routes`.

I have looked inside the `console` script file, and it looks like `app.php` but we call it only once, at the start of the server. Where is the glue stuff ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `console` file is the front-controller for the CLI environment of your Symfony application. The `server:run` is part of this environment and can be found in the FrameworkBundle: [`ServerRunCommand`](https://github.com/symfony/FrameworkBundle/blob/master/Command/ServerRunCommand.php) (EDIT: as of Symfony 3.3, the command can be found in [the WebServerBundle](https://github.com/symfony/web-server-bundle/blob/master/Command/ServerRunCommand.php))

It starts the built-in webserver of PHP: `php -S localhost:8000` and it routes all incomming requests to a so-called routing script. In case of the dev environment, the [`router_dev.php`](https://github.com/symfony/FrameworkBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/router_dev.php) router inside the FrameworkBundle.

This router file has this line:

```
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'app_dev.php';
```

Which pretends that the incomming request was made to the `app_dev.php` file. (So `localhost:8000/something` becomes `localhost:8000/app_dev.php/something` after this router script). It then includes the `app_dev.php` file to handle the rendering of the site.